UE Git cloning stuck at 0%
I am trying to create a repository to add an Unreal Engine project. I found that my cPanel has Git™ Version Control, so I created one and was able to push my Unreal project.
I have a second computer, and when I try to clone the repository, it gets stuck at 0%.
Here is the output:
Cloning into '***'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 25418, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (25418/25418), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17378/17378), done.
Receiving objects:   0% (1/25418)

I have no idea why it's hanging at 0%. I’ve checked my internet connection, and the server is reachable.
Some information:

I am using Windows on both computers.
I am cloning the repo using SSH.
The repository has a large number of files (~25,000 objects).
I’ve tried using Git Bash, Git GUI, Sourcetree, and Git Extension, but the same issue occurs with all of them.

Has anyone encountered this before or have suggestions on what could be causing this issue?

I had the same issue this week. Problem was new Git version 2.47.0
git -v
git version 2.47.0.windows.1

Reverted back to 2.46.2 and it is working again
winget uninstall Git.Git
winget install Git.Git --version 2.46.2

Not quite sure where that version came from. Winget doesn't offer that version at the moment.

same here, switching back to 2.46.2 helped
